# Adding commas at the end of each line when importing CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I am quite new to PHP and need your help for an issue. I will explain my problem in the following steps:

1- I have a CSV file and I would like to import it to MySQL database with PHP.

2- When I add commas at the end of each lines in the CSV file, I could import it by using IMPORT option in Mysql db. I can not import it without adding commas at the end of lines.

3- I want to add a new line into my PHP code which will add commas at the end of each record/line and will enable the data imported without any error.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

//read file
$csvfile=file_get_contents("/samba/import/Tbl_HRList.csv");


$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvfile);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $field = str_getcsv($line);
    if ($field[0] != ''){

        $sql="INSERT INTO HR_Tbl (Employee_ID, First Name, Prefix, Surname, Location, Organizational Code, Organizational Unit, Team, Team Code, Function, Function code, T24 Department Code, Date in service (GBI), Company email, End Date Contract, End Date Systems, Temp. Leave Date, Temp. Leave End, Temp. Leave Code)
                VALUES
('$field[0]','$field[1]','$field[2]','$field[3]','$field[4]','$field[5]','$field[6]','$field[7]','$field[8]','$field[9]','$field[10]','$field[11]','$field[12]','$field[13]','$field[14]','$field[15]','$field[16]','$field[17]','$field[18])";

    }

    //insert record to database

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully". PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
else
{
continue;
}
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: what is the `else` at the end ?? it comes after the foreach... it should be after an if...

Comment: It is bound to "check connection" constant which was before all this code line. Sorry, I didnt put this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Load Data Infile` and **completely** abandon the above idea.

You can have csv lines terminate with `\n` or `\r\n`

You can have row one of that import file either have or not have column names.
if you have column names, you skip the first row.

If you have column names on row1, you can have, say, 12 columns, and just use 4 if you want.

It is a very flexible construct. Check it out.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: I can not use this option since db requires password. Actually, I am planning to import the file each Friday morning, so  it is better to use a script in PHP. I think.

Comment: are you saying that file for import does not exist on the server? you are already connected to the db, so db password is irrelevant. you only need to path to the import csv

Comment: `load data infile` is like a select statement. your only issue is pathing to file

Comment: if you want to import the same file name every Friday morning, use mysql `create event` (scheduled to run every Friday) that contains whatever, including `load data infile` **query** if you will :>

Comment: @AlexNoord It is possible to execute SQL with cron as well, and if you don't want to execute it directly you could still use a PHP script to call the `LOAD DATA INFILE...`.

Comment: Ok. Now It worked. I just missed to use ignoring lines like Drew mentioned above. Thanks for your help guys!